# com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to rebuild my project which I've written in kotlin but it has constantly failed with the error

```
Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes
```

I've tried

- Invalidating cache
- cleaning and rebuilding
- using `./gradlew build --stacktrace --info` command

but without success.

Exception is

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'
```

Stack trace is

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 111 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:143)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        ... 124 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes
        at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:128)
        ... 127 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:124)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:123)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
        at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:41)
        at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:111)
        at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
        ... 128 more
```

My app's build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    //support
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$androidX"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidX"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidX"
    implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:$androidX"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidX"
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette:$androidX"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$androidX"

    //architecture
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$architectureVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$architectureVersionExt"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$androidX"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$architectureVersion"

    //data binding
    //kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.0-alpha04"

    //glide
    //kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"
    //implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:4.8.0-SNAPSHOT'

    //dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"

    // if you use the support libraries
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    //reactiveX
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroidVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rxKotlinVersion"

    //
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$rxBinding"
    implementation "com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:$rxPermissions"

    //ucrop
    implementation "com.github.yalantis:ucrop:$uCrop"

    //other libraries
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson"
    implementation "com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:$phoneLibVersion"

    //map and places
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$mapVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$mapVersion"

    //
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.0'

    //retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit"
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$androidX"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    ext.realmVersion ='5.4.2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name 'glide-snapshot'
            url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realmVersion"
        //classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            name 'glide-snapshot'
            url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        google()
    }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000"
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Configure common tasks on all the submodules
 */
allprojects { project ->

    // Get versions, this is where we store things
    // like the list of submodules or the version
    project.apply from: "$rootDir/versions.gradle"
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Seeing the same with @AnyRes could this be a bug?  Tried turning off multidex and everything you tried + more...

Comment: @fattire I managed to solve the error. see my answer below

Answer (score 51, accepted):

After struggling and struggling and looking for help here and there, I discovered that `./gradlew app:dependencies` command was providing important output to solve the error.

First of all, the error is `Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes`

`Program type already present` means there is a naming conflict, and in this case the androidx.annotation library, which is use by several libraries.That is other libraries contain  `androidx.annotation library` as a transitive dependency. To see this libraries, i opened the terminal from my project's root folder(my OS is Ubuntu) and run `./gradlew app:dependencies` command. It produced a long list of configurations and their dependences. below is an extract.

```
debugCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debug

+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0-alpha07
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0-alpha07
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 -> 2.0.0-rc01
|    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0-rc02
|    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0-rc02
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0-rc02
|    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1 -> 1.0.0-rc02
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc02
|    \--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0-alpha07
+--- androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:3.3.0-alpha07
|    +--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0-alpha07
|    \--- androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0-alpha07 (*)
```

The above extract shows some of dependencies for `debugCompileClasspath` configuration.We can see that `androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:3.3.0-alpha07` contains `androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc02` as a transitive dependency.

It also contains `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1` which in turns contain `androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01`.

`androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0-rc02` means that version `1.0.0-rc02` will be used instead of version `1.0.0-rc01` .

Below is another extract from the same long output produced by `./gradlew app:dependencies`

```
kapt
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
|    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 23.3-jre
|    |         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
|    |         +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    |         \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
|    \--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
```

From the above, we can see that `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1` contains version `1.0.0-alpha1` of `androidx.annotation:annotation`

This means at the end, my module `app` will have two versions `1.0.0-alpha1` and `1.0.0-rc02` which makes build to fail.

To solve this error, i just removed the transitive dependencies by adding the below block of code in my app's build.gradle

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation'
}
```

So my app's build.gradle will look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    //bla bla bla
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation'
}

dependencies {
// bla bla bla
}
```

After that, i just synced,cleaned and rebuild my project.

Comment: Wow- I had tried checking the dependencies (as recommended in the error message) and in my case every single instance, `androidx.annotations` was either `rc02` OR `androidx.annotations:annotations:1.0.0-rc01 -> 1.0.0-rc02`. I just double-checked again and unless it's very subtle and I'm just missing it, I dunno where it's getting tripped up.  Regardless, I gave your configurations line a shot, cleaned the project, and... it built and installed!  Nice job finding a solution.  I just wish I knew why I was having the issue to begin with... ah well :)

Comment: Unfortunately, if I cleaned again, it wiped out *both* copies of annotation.... See [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/113119760) tho.  It seems that the prebuilt renderscript support library has a few errors and hopefully will be fixed soon.

Comment: @fattire I have seen the posted bug on issuetracker. As for me, I'm using `implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02` instead of `implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01` but I never encountered the mentioned error even after cleaning and rebuilding again

Comment: You are a hero!

Comment: The search for this type of error is unfortunately resembling a "mystery tour" using Android Studio and Gradle. Why don't the compiler state something like this: "error; module A is using lib x.x.x, while module B is using lib x.x.y. Suggestion for correction: ……" This is 2019 after all. What a timethief these types of error is.

Comment: Found a cause for this error: Had a "compile" leftover in some upper level module A, not replaced with "implementation". The former is deprecated. This produced this error "Program type already present...." in a module B, even if the library was not added as a dependency in module B. IOW, completely "greek" error message.

Answer (score 21):

To solve this problem I write the command `./gradlew clean` in Android Studio terminal and voilà !

Comment: Or Build -> Clean project (in Android Studio)

Comment: @AITAALI :  Unfortunately, I don't use "Android Studio", and I only use Unity 2019. Would you please show me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: @Moos Trafic :  Unfortunately, I don't use "Android Studio", and I only use Unity 2019. Would you please show me how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just clean the project and rebuild it and it worked.

- Build -> Clean project
- Build -> Rebuild project

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this same error, solved by adding these lines in Gradle.

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw/master"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84'  // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` in app gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in my CI environment because I was using [jdk8-openj9](https://hub.docker.com/layers/adoptopenjdk/library/adoptopenjdk/8-openj9-bionic/images/sha256-5b721403c6ad6da77e798dd8e13fa2bc8bd34bb6376d801dcf96a6bc15ba9abb?context=explore) jdk from docker.

Switching to [openjdk-8](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/8-slim-buster/images/sha256-2d2db0073c3396b624d1783a0e23e1a317204fb729d22604a43e0fa8d1e88ae1?context=explore) docker image solved the issue.