# Build errors after updating Gradle dependencies. Suspect #1 is firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I have an app that builds just fine, but starts failing as soon as I try to update some Gradle dependencies, whereas the main suspect is firebase.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException:
>   com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

And this is the git diff for my project, showing the differences in the Gradle files:

```
diff --git a/android/build.gradle b/android/build.gradle
index 9f63f745..08fda2eb 100644
--- a/android/build.gradle
+++ b/android/build.gradle
@@ -81,8 +81,8 @@ dependencies {
     implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
     implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
     implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$playBillingLibVersion"
-    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
-    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
+    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
+    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0"
     implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
diff --git a/android_common/build.gradle b/android_common/build.gradle
index f8224509..3a5d45e1 100644
--- a/android_common/build.gradle
+++ b/android_common/build.gradle
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@ android {
         androidTest.setRoot('tests')
     }
     defaultConfig {
-        minSdkVersion 15
+        minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
@@ -65,8 +65,8 @@ dependencies {
     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
     natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
     implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$playBillingLibVersion"
-    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
-    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
+    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
+    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0"

     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
diff --git a/android_instant_feature/build.gradle b/android_instant_feature/build.gradle
index 30431c11..17c4ef27 100644
--- a/android_instant_feature/build.gradle
+++ b/android_instant_feature/build.gradle
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ android {
     defaultConfig {
         versionCode 4031
         versionName "4.1.2.1i"
-        minSdkVersion 15
+        minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 28
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
@@ -77,8 +77,8 @@ dependencies {
     api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
     implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
     implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
-    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
-    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:16.0.0'
+    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
+    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:16.0.1'

     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 }
diff --git a/core/build.gradle b/core/build.gradle
index dd2640cf..5694a1da 100644
--- a/core/build.gradle
+++ b/core/build.gradle
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@ dependencies {
     compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
     // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
     compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'
-    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
+    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
     compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.2'
     compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
     compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '16.0.1'
@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@ dependencies {
     implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"

     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
-    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
+    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
     testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '1.7.3'
     testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.3'
 }
```

Please, note that some of these changes like the minSDKVersion can be discarded as the source of the error. It seems most likely it is related to firebase. Why? Well, among other things there are other questions in Stackoverflow in which that's the case, however the solution proposed in all of these is to update firebase dependencies to last version, **but updating firebase dependencies to last version is what it seems to be causing the problem in my project!** With the old versions it just builds fine.

These are the contents of the Gradle scripts involved (I have replaced the actual applicationId with 'com.myapp.id')

:core

```
apply plugin: "java"

targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/main"]
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["src/test"]

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1'
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

:android_common

```
apply plugin: "com.android.feature"

configurations { natives }

android {
    baseFeature true
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        sourceSets {
            all {
                manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            setMinifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    application project(':android')
    feature project(':android_instant_feature')
    api project(':core')
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-x86_64"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT:natives-x86_64"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0"

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-android'
}

task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

:android

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // Needed by crashlytics. DO NOT REMOVE.

android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ["${project(':android_common').projectDir}/res"]
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.id"
        versionCode 4032
        versionName "4.1.2.1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    // Proguard configuration
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

task importPuzzles(type: Exec) {
    // TODO
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.myapp.id/com.myapp.id.AndroidLauncher'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":android_common")
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

:android_instant_feature

```
apply plugin: "com.android.feature"

android {
//    baseFeature true
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ["${project(':android_common').projectDir}/res"]
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 4031
        versionName "4.1.2.1i"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    // Proguard configuration
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
//            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {}
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.myapp.id/com.myapp.id.AndroidLauncher'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":android_common")
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.9-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:16.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Finally, this is the structure of my project. The most relevant part as it's android related is the one on the top. Below I just show how it's related to the core module.

[image]

This is a libGDX game and I'm working with IntelliJ Idea, though this is not relevant since I'm getting these errors with ./gradlew build in the command line.

---

EDIT: I downgraded firebase-core from 16.0.5 to 16.0.4 as suggested by TWL and it worked, so I think it's an acceptable workaround, at least while the firebase guys release a firebase-core 16.0.6 or so actually compatible with firebase-ads 17.0.0. The problem seems to be effectively that firebase-ads 17.0.0 relies on a older version of the library that's causing the error.

Look at these dependencies outputs:

This is what I get with firebase-core 16.0.4:

```
$ ./gradlew android_common:dependencies | grep measurement-base
<-------------> 0% EXECUTING [0s]
> :android_common:dependencies
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3
```

... (and so on, all 16.0.3 straight forward)

And this for firebase-core 16.0.5:

```
$ ./gradlew android_common:dependencies | grep measurement-base
<-------------> 0% EXECUTING [1s]
> :android_common:dependencies > Resolve dependencies of :android_common:releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4] -> 16.0.4 (*)
```

As you see, there are some entries like "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.3 -> 16.0.4 (*)" that, despite I'm not proficient on interpreting these outputs, I think are the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alright, since all comments have been moved to chat and my temporary workaround was there too, here it is then:*

Your error message brought my searching to [com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: androidx.annotation.AnimRes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002186/com-android-tools-r8-errors-compilationerror-program-type-already-present-andr)

> Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException:
>   com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: ___

That error suggests there is a duplicate dependency somewhere that is running off two different versions. Then the goal is to run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to produce a tree/list of the dependencies to look for `com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz`. The problem is that this is obfuscated and an internal private package, so it won't be directly found in the list, but the keyword `measurement` is a hint.

This led me to notice that `core` and `ads` have something similar: `play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3] -> 16.0.3 (*)` and `play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.2`. With testing, I found two workarounds:

1. downgrade `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5` to `16.0.4`
2. add `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-measurement-sdk-api'` to the `ads` dependency

**First** option is probably safer to do, since a re-run of `./gradlew app:dependencies` showed that `play-services-measurement-api` and `play-services-measurement-sdk-api` were both now `16.0.2`.

And I'm sure Google/Firebase is aware of this since I did just find another mention of it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119213680 The translation is: *The error is duplicate of class zzdz, the transition of the existence status of zzdz class is as follows*. So beware that `play-services-measurement-sdk-api` can run into issues with other Firebase/GMS libraries. There should be an upcoming fix to update it.

*Note that even switching to `"com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0"` will still cause this error.