# Error: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz

Tags: android

I really don't know what's going on, I've searched everything and nothing worked. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate. I change all dependencies and libraries to try to solve it, but nothing worked.

Yesterday,my app was working fine.

Today, I don't know why, the app didn't compile anymore after I reopened the Android Studio.

Here is build.gradle Project

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

}

Here is build.gradle Project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: Your `google-services` classpath is outdated.

Comment: What's your full error message? Is it something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208575/build-errors-after-updating-gradle-dependencies-suspect-1-is-firebase/